# MAAS KVM nodes commission timesout

Tags: virtualization, maas, kvm-virtualization, qemu

So, I have set up MAAS and several KVM and Qemu VMs. When I add them as nodes, they start up during commissioning but then the attempt times out. Here's the line from the MAAS log:

```
[ERROR] test: Marking node failed: Node operation 'Commissioning' timed out after 0:20:00.
```

The `maas` user has been added to `libvirtd`. I even added the user to `sudoers`.

I've gone over old bug reports and updated MAAS to the latest version.

The setup is straight from the guide, I have the power as `Virsh` and the address as `qemu:///system`.

Running the `virsh` commands from command line as `maas` user works fine.

Not sure what else to try. Any help appreciated.

Edit: also if I use the webui and try to commission again after a timeout it says "Node failed to be commissioned, because of the following error: Unable to be commissioned because the power is currently on." Thanks MAAS!

Comment: did you try using qemu+ssh? I am having the same problem as you...